# How do I change the color of words in AppBar title separately

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a simple home assistant app and I want to display connection status in AppBar title. I want to have one part of the title colored in light grey and the second part colored in green if the bridge is connected or in red, if the bridge is disconnected.

Here's a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image: what I want it to look like]

[image]

How can I do it? Is this even possible?

I've also posted a code below of what I have for now - this is just a single colored title

`activity_main.xml`

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            style="@style/AppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
            app:title="@string/appbar_title"
            app:titleMarginStart="24dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

`themes.xml`

```xml
    <style name="AppBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/light_gray</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Spans and Spannable strings. See the guide to [Spans](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans) for further instructions and examples.